# Adding all the number of a one string together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to take the string '27 4 2019' 
and output the sum of 2050. Not in a string.

So far I have split it.

```
let x = '27 4 2019'
console.log(x.split('').?
```

I'm not sure how to add the numbers together after splitting it.

Comment: Is that supposed to represent a date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 2):

Split based on whitespace, and `reduce` while converting into numbers:

```js
const str = "27 4 2019";
const output = str.split(/\s/).reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b), 0);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your amazing.

Comment: No worries @Jacob, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to:

1. [split()](http://split()) the `String` to array values using a `whitespace ' '` as a separator.
2. [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array values from `String` type to `Number`.
3. [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array to a single value.

```js
const s = '27 4 2019';

const out = s.split(' ').map(Number).reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegEx `replace` function to iterate through all your numerical elements and add them. `+n` acts as an operator to coerce the string to a number, which you know will work because we're only grabbing numerical elements from the string. This also has the added benefit of passing over the string once, where other answers may go through it several times, and it doesn't require coercion of your string to an array.

```
let total;
string.replace(/[0-9]/g, (n) => total = total ? total + (+n) : +n);
```

```js
let x = '27 4 2019', total;
x.replace(/[0-9]/g, (n) => total = total ? total + (+n) : +n);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution could be to use `regex` to find numbers in a string and pass a supporting function to ad them up as

```js
let x = '27 4 2019', total = 0;
x.replace(/\d+/g, (obj) => total += +obj);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Why this is efficient

Comment: @srknzl changed the wording