# Using a single coordinates variable to select center in Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-api-3

I have a variable called coordinates that is formatted like this:

`var coordinates = 'lat / lon';`

I now want to extract the single lat and lon coordinate from that variable to display it as the center in a Google Maps API Map.
I have tried using slice to get the specific parts of the coordinates variable but depending on what coordinate it is the length is different, for example:

`var coordinates = '49.7824 / 7.2413';`
`var coordinates = '8.5323 / -11.3336';`

Is there any other way I could use those coordinates as the map center with the Maps API?

Comment: Have you considered `coordinates.split(" / ")[0]` ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var coordinates = '49.7824 / 7.2413';
const [lgt, lat] = coordinates.split('/');
```

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that have been answered already (and multiple times). Instead, point the OP to the duplicate Q/A in a comment. Once you will have sufficient reputation, you will earn the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to cast close votes.