# i want to split a result in mysql can you help me?

Tags: mysql, discord, discord.js, heidisql

Well, first that's my code here

```
client.on('message', async (message) => { //فايف ام داتابيس
  if(message.channel.type == 'dm') return;
  var prefix = prefixx.get(message.guild.id);
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'ip')) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send('ما عندك رتبة عشان تستخدم الأمر هذا');
  let args = message.content.split(" ");
      connection1.query(
          `select ifnull((select last_login from vrp_users where id = ${args[1]}),'لا يوجد ايدي بهذا الرقم') As ResultFound`, function (error, result, fields) {
              if (error) throw error;
              console.log(`Got IP of user ${args[1]}`);
              if(!result) return message.channel.send('There is an error');
              if(error) return message.channel.send('There is an error');
              let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() .setColor('RANDOM') .setTitle(`اي بي ${args[1]}`) .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL( { dynamic : true } )) .setAuthor(client.user.tag, client.user.avatarURL( {dynamic : true} )) .addField('IP', `\`${result[0].ResultFound}\``); 
              message.channel.send(embed)
          }
          
      );
          
  }
});
```

the result comes like this :

```
77.223.232.147 23:50:55 29/06/2020
```

i want the result be only the ip can you guys help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
.addField('IP', `\`${result[0].ResultFound.split(' ')[0]}\``);
```

---

For example, if the result is what you provided in your question:

```js
const result = '77.223.232.147 23:50:55 29/06/2020'

// split the message by every space
const array = result.split(' ');

console.log(array[0]); // IP adress
console.log(array[1]); // time (I presume)
console.log(array[2]); // date
```

Comment: no i don't want this ip only i want for every strings in the table

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i mean when i type '!ip 1' it logs this ip but i want to split every result not only this result

Comment: Check my edited answer. The method I provided can do that, I was just using what you gave as an example.