# How to divide a string into an object by '.'?

Tags: javascript

How to divide a string into an object by '.' ?

`'a.b.c'`

to:

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string by `.`s, reverse it, and use `reduceRight` to built it up from the inner parts outward:

```js
const str = 'a.b.c';

const obj = str
  .split('.')
  .reduceRight(
    (innerObj, propName) => ({ [propName]: innerObj }),
    {}
  );
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = 'a.b.c';

const res = input.split('.').reverse().reduce((acc, cur)=>{
  const _acc = {};
  _acc[cur] = acc;
  return _acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```