# Find specific Character in string and dont display the rest

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do have the following string:
AAAAAAA | BBBBBBBB | CCCCCCCC | DDDDDDDD

Only the AAAAAA part should be visible.
Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character

Comment: What do you mean by “visible”? Where are your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split method like this:
`inputString.split('|')[0]`