# How to split a string into individual elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a need to split a string in javascript to individual components. Let me go through the example of the requirement I'm having.

This is the string I'm having:

```
"[InsertDelta, position: 63, lines: [return {]]"
```

I need to split the above string into three components as below:

```
InsertDela
position: 63
lines: [return {]
```

Is there any way to separate the strings like this in javascript?

Comment: So java or javascript? Please choose one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca javascript will be ideal choice for my requirement

Comment: Then something like `"[InsertDelta, position: 63, lines: [return {]]".replace(/[\[\]]/, '').split(', ')` should do the trick.

Comment: The dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split to split the string at "," and then use for each to iterate through the items.

```js
let y = "[InsertDelta, position: 63, lines: [return {]]";
let x = y.split(",");
x.forEach(item => console.log(item.replace(/\[?\]?/g, "")));
```

Comment: `", "`, with a space after the comma.

Comment: Also, you're keeping the `[` and `]` at the start and end of the string (the one from OP has a double `]` at the end)

Comment: I have removed the brackets.