# How to extract specific words from a string with some patterns?

Tags: javascript

I am **trying to extract some strings from a word with some pattern** like -

```
"38384-1-page1-2222", "1-22-page33-02", "99-222-frontpage-111"
```

**how will I extract all word between** `-` separately, means first word before `-` and then second word between `-` and `-` and so on...

```
string = "38384-1-page1-2222";
string.substr(0, string.indexof("-")); //return 38384
```

But how will I extract `1`, `page1` and `2222`  all the words separately?

Comment: `string.split("-");` ?

Comment: Why not using the str split function?  
Something like `const splitedText= text.split("-");`  
[Check this out.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: I understood but how will I get ll the values i.e. 4 values separately so that I will assign that values separately ?

Comment: @herostoky this `string.split("-")` gives me values at once so I will not able to use them separately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript function `str.split(separator)` split the **string** by the given **separator** and it returns an **array** of all the splited string. [REF Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Here is an example following your question :

```
var string = "38384-1-page1-2222";
var separator = "-";

var separated = string.split(separator);

var firstString = separated[0];  // will be '38384'
var secondString = separated[1]; // will be '1'
var thirdString = separated[2];  // will be 'page1'
/* And So on ... */
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this can help

Use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get your string into array

```js
var words = ["38384-1-page1-2222", "1-22-page33-02", "99-222-frontpage-111"];

var resultArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < words.length;i++) {
  let temp = words[i];
  resultArray = pushArray(temp.split("-"), resultArray)
}

console.log(resultArray)

function pushArray (inputArray, output) {
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length;i++) {
   output.push(inputArray[i]);
  }
  return output;
}
```

Or simply use **[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**

```js
var words = ["38384-1-page1-2222", "1-22-page33-02", "99-222-frontpage-111"];

var result = words.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue.concat(currentValue.split("-")), []) 

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `/[^-]+/g`

```js
const words = ["38384-1-page1-2222", "1-22-page33-02", "99-222-frontpage-111"];

console.log(words.map(v=>v.match(/[^-]+/g)).flat())
```

Comment: I don't know the `flat()` until now, this solution is better than me